# global name 'ParseError' is not defined, I used try and except to avoid it but this still shows up

Tags: python, django

it's occurring from the line with except ParseError which I don't understand, because I wrote this line to avoid this error. Here's my code

```
import json
from goose import Goose

DEFAULT = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1427435150519-42d9bcd0aa81?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=10d1cfc208c8ed5ed1160e851eabce1d'
def extract(url):
    g = Goose()
    try:
        article = g.extract(url=url)
        if article.top_image is None:
            return DEFAULT 

        else:
            if article.top_image.src is None:
              return DEFAULT
            else:
                resposne = {'image':article.top_image.src}
                return article.top_image.src
    except ParseError:
        if can_handle():
                handle_exception()
            else:
                print("couldn't handle exception: url={0}".format(url))
                raise
```

I mainly just want to avoid this error, if I get this error I want just default image to show up. What am I missing here?

Here;s my traceback

```
Traceback:
File "/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  34.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  30.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "/home/younggue/Desktop/ebagu0.2/rclone/main/views.py" in dispatch
  172.      return super(PostCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)       
File "/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  249.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  215.             return self.form_valid(form)
File "main/views.py" in form_valid
  165.          self.object.image = extract(self.object.url) 
File "main/util/media.py" in extract
  18.   except ParseError:

Exception Type: NameError at /add_post/
Exception Value: global name 'ParseError' is not defined
```

Comment: I think you'll have to write `from goose import *` or `from goose import Goose, ParseError`

Comment: @dazedconfused hmm I don't think that's the right solution ...highly doubt parseerror is from goose

Comment: Don't think there's a built-in `ParseError` exception, the only one I know is `xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError`

Comment: @dazedconfused really I didn't know that...I tried importing ParseError from goose but I get cannot import parseError....is there anyway to just avoid this error beside what I tried?

Comment: The error is appearing because of your exception handling... but what exception is it that you're actually trying to catch? What do you expect to throw the `ParseError`? Since it is a class that doesn't exist you can currently just delete the entire exception block

Comment: @Sayse I'm simpy trying to catch ParseError with try and except. I thought it worked till now. I insert url and image gets extracted but sometimes when I insert url I get parseError which in this case I want to display default image instead. Do you know the solution to this?

Comment: Trigger the error, and look in the stack trace for the full namespace for the error and then import it from there.

Answer (score 10):

I got this same error when using pandas to iteratively load files from a list of files.  Following @Sayse's comment, after running the code, I found `lib/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py` in the stack trace.

To correct the problem, I had to import that error from the file in which it is define.  In my case, I used

```
import pandas as pd
#~~~~~~~~~~ Solution: import the error ~~~~~~~~~~
from pandas.errors import ParserError
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
for fname in fnames:
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(fname)
    except ParserError:
        logger.info(f'Skipping incompatible file: {fname}')
```

Comment: This might be from an older version of Pandas. For Python 3.9.10 and Pandas 1.4.1, the following line works instead: `from pandas.errors import ParserError`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.errors.ParserError.html)

```
from pandas.errors import ParserError
try:
    ...
except ParserError:
    ...
```

or simple

```
except pd.errors.ParserError  as text_exception:
```

Answer (score 1):

Latest version of Pandas (v2.0.0) includes the ParserError you can call.  I correctly caught this parser error by implementing the following:

```
import pandas as pd

try:
  pd.read_csv(path)
except pd.errors.ParserError:
  print("Parsing Error!")
```